SQL WHERE clause that allows for an Exact or Contains statement on the same column
I want to return the invoice number if it contains a value or is an exact value, with the exact value having priority to the contains value.
For instance if the invoice numbers are 123 and 1234.
I want to write - Example 1:
INPUT1 = '123'
INPUT2 = ''

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    INV_NUM = INPUT1
    OR INV_NUM LIKE '%INPUT2%'

The result returns both 123 and 1234.
Desired result is to return only 123.
However if I don't know the exact number I'd like to use input2 to find contains - example 2:
INPUT1 = ''
INPUT2 = '4'

-- same statement
SELECT
    *
FROM  
    TABLE
WHERE 
    INV_NUM = INPUT1
    OR INV_NUM LIKE '%INPUT2%'

Result should return 123 and 1234 because of the or.
Desired results would be to return 1234 only.
How can I write it so it prioritized exact match, but if exact match is blank it will only use contains input?
Using Oracle if that matters.

If you search for 4 and the data contains 40 and 14, what should be returned? Please edit you question with the missing details, in the form of a [mre]

In input 1 or 2? In 1 it should return none because it's not an exact match. Input 2 it should return both 40 and 14 because it's a contains.

You can order the rows based on your priority and then fetch only the rows with the highest priority:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  INV_NUM = :INPUT1
OR     INV_NUM LIKE '%' || :INPUT2 || '%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN INV_NUM = :INPUT1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;


You can try something like below.
SELECT *
FROM Invoice
WHERE INV_NUM = INPUT1
      OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Invoice WHERE INV_NUM = INPUT1) 
         AND INV_NUM LIKE '%'||INPUT2||'%';


One option is to join your data with the input parameters selected from Dual and find the matches using Case expressions:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
    tbl AS
        ( Select '123' "ID" From Dual Union All
          Select '1234' From Dual
        )

--      S Q L : 
SELECT ID 
FROM ( Select t.ID, p.INPUT_1, p.INPUT_2, 
              Case When t.ID = p.INPUT_1 Then t.ID 
              Else 
                   Case When Count( Case When t.ID = p.INPUT_1  Then t.ID End ) Over() = 0
                        Then Case When InStr( t.ID, p.INPUT_2 ) > 0 Then t.ID End
                   End     
              End match_id
       From   tbl t
       Left Join ( Select :INPUT_1 "INPUT_1", :INPUT_2 "INPUT_2" From Dual ) p ON(p.INPUT_1 = t.ID OR t.ID Like '%' || p.INPUT_2 || '%')
     ) 
WHERE ID = match_id 

--  Result for INPUT_1 = '123'  /  INPUT_2 = '4'
   ID
-----
  123

--  Result for INPUT_1 = ''  /  INPUT_2 = '4'
   ID
-----
 1234

--  Result for INPUT_1 = '1234'  /  INPUT_2 = '3'
   ID
-----
 1234

--  Result for INPUT_1 = ''  /  INPUT_2 = '3'
   ID
-----
  123
 1234

